# Find derivative of $\ln{\frac{\sqrt{1-\sin x}}{\sqrt{1 + \sin x}}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Find derivative of $\ln{\frac{\sqrt{1-\sin x}}{\sqrt{1 + \sin x}}}$

i tried to simplify it with log identity become $\frac 12 [ \log{(1 - \sin x)} - \log{(1 + \sin x)} ]$

i tried to simplify it with factorization $\log{\frac{\sqrt{1-\sin x}}{\sqrt{1 + \sin x}}}\sqrt{\frac{1 + \sin x}{1 + \sin x}}$ become $\log{\frac{\cos x}{1 + \sin x}}$

Then, how do i actually find the derivative?

Comment: Your first attempt seems pretty close using the chain rule.

Answer (score 2):

$f(x) = \log{\frac{\sqrt{1-\sin x}}{\sqrt{1 + \sin x}}} = \frac 12 [ \log{(1 - \sin x)} - \log{(1 + \sin x)} ]$

Differentiating the RHS with respect to $x$, we get

$f'(x) = \dfrac{1}{2} \left(\dfrac{-\cos(x)}{1 - \sin(x)} - \dfrac{\cos(x)}{1 + \sin(x)}\right)$

Comment: I think you have a sign error (the derivative of $-\log(1+\sin x)$ is $-\frac{\cos x}{1+\sin x}$).

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. I've edited it.

Answer (score 2):

To make this easier, we will define $u=\sin(x), y=\ln(\frac{\sqrt{1-\sin(x)}}{\sqrt{1+\sin(x)}})$.

We then note that $\tanh^{-1}(u)=\ln(\frac{\sqrt{1+u}}{\sqrt{1-u}})$, and therefore $y=-\tanh^{-1}(u)$.

Differentiating via the chain rule, we get:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du}\cdot\frac{du}{dx}=-\frac{1}{1-u^2(x)}\cdot\cos(x)=-\frac{1}{1-\sin^2(x)}\cdot\cos(x)=-\frac{\cos(x)}{\cos^2(x)}=-\sec(x)$$

Answer (score 2):

Your second attempt is pretty close as well.

$$f(x) =\ln \left( \frac{\cos x}{1 + \sin x}\frac{\sec x}{\sec x} \right) =\ln \left( \frac{1}{\sec x + \tan x}\right) = -\ln(\sec x +\tan x)$$

so:

$$f'(x) = -\sec x.$$